# FailSafe Feature

Tags: java, iterator

Before asking this question I have tried understanding (here on SOF and on some other websites) fail-safe feature. I understand Java Collection Iterators are fail-fast, which basically means they fail gracefully as soon as underlying Collection is being structurally modified (even by the same thread). My question is does fail-safe property have anything to do with Iterators' remove() or add() features? In my understanding because through Iterators you can add or remove (safely) while iterating over a Collection and you wont get a concurrent exception (that you do without using their remove and add features), so that makes Iterators fail-safe. Or I have got it completely wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly. In my understanding fail-safe iterators work on snapshots of data and guarantee consistent view of the represented collection on the moment when the iterator has been created. (please see [this blog post](http://www.certpal.com/blogs/2009/09/iterators-fail-fast-vs-fail-safe/) for more detailed treatment of this question). This property is guaranteed f.i. by iterators of the `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. It's iterators do not support collection modification operations and its javadoc clarifies their behavior further:

> This array never changes during the
>   lifetime of the iterator, so
>   interference is impossible and the
>   iterator is guaranteed not to throw
>   ConcurrentModificationException. The
>   iterator will not reflect additions,
>   removals, or changes to the list since
>   the iterator was created.
>   Element-changing operations on
>   iterators themselves (remove, set, and
>   add) are not supported. These methods
>   throw UnsupportedOperationException.

**UPDATE:**

When talking about fail-safeness and fail-fastness it is important to separate "the failure". In case of iterator there are different cases and hazards. As for the linked article I would say that there author implements fail-safe and fail-fast **iteration** at the first place by implementing iterators.

The failure in that case can be defined as concurrent modification of the iterated collection. When the collection is modified then fail-fast approach will be to stop iteration and to make the caller aware of the changed conditions (via `CME` or by some other means).

When dealing with the same use-case and hazard we can move forward and think about fail-safe iteration. Fail-safeness property means that iteration should comply to its contract as long as it possible (and authors of the `COWAS` succeed by copying underlying data).

Comment: Thanks Alex, I think I have read this blog before and I could not get answer to my question, he creates two iterators, one with and other without copy, and then says one without copy would throw an  exception on modification. I think you can have fail-safe even without copy as well, you just need to keep checking for any modification.

Comment: Fail-safe is just a property and his implementation guarantees it by providing a copy. If you can guarantee fail-safeness by another means its up to you. When you check for modification and find that the collection is modified what will you do to guarantee this property? BTW have you read references to wikipedia given in that blog post?

Comment: you said "fail-safe iterators work on snapshots of data and guarantee consistent view of the represented collection on the moment when the iterator has been created", it means you either have fail-safe iterators or fail-fast, whereas this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345250/are-fail-fast-and-fail-safe-exception-handling-principles-incompatible) post says the two are not opposite.

Comment: @WReach gives good explanation with the examples. I think it will be helpful to abstract away from iterators and to understand these two properties first. What is fail-safe and what is fail-fast in general. And move to iterators then. As you can see from the `CopyOnWriteArrayList`'s javadoc it throws `UnsupportedOperationException` that is an example of the "fail-fast" behaviour (By throwing an exception it says: if you're modifying this via an iterator collection then you are doing something wrong). These properties are not opposite.

Comment: @Alex, you are right, once the collection has been modified, Iterator has to fail-fast. Please comment on my last comment as well. Thanks

Comment: @Abidi, by saying "fail-safe iterators work on snapshots of data and guarantee consistent view of the represented collection on the moment when the iterator has been created" I meant nothing about oppositeness of fail-safe and fail-fast properties. I think that fail-safeness can be (and should be) implemented by different means depending on your requirements. And probably creating a copy is not the only way of implementing a fail-safe iterator (iterator is a concept, just like fail-safe and fail-fast).

Comment: @Alex, I think both of these terms can be considered opposite and complementary, but I get your point. If I have to define them in one line I would say, "Fail-Safe software would try handling the failure gracefully AND would move on without jeopardizing the application's validity/integrity whereas on failure Fail-Fast would notify the caller and abandon that path of execution".

Comment: Link is broken, kindly fix it.

Comment: @SandeepJindal, just checked it -- seems to be ok.

Answer (score 0):

The `Iterator` or `ListIterator` work on the underlying collection is a way which doesn't not invalidate that Iterator. Any modification via any other iterator or the collection itself, invalidates the iterator for some collections.  Some collections are designed for concurrent access and don't have this restriction.

Comment: "doesn't not invalidate": I assume you mean "doesn't invalidate"?